# I want to read a certain part of a line in C

Tags: c, file

I want to read a specific part of a line. I don't want to add anything after "// " as shown in the example. I've defined a flag for it. But I'm having a hard time getting to the bottom line. How can I solve this ?

```
void read_file(char *filename) {
    int flag = 0;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    while(fscanf(f, "%s", line) != EOF) {
        if(!strcmp(line, "//")) {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if(flag == 0) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }       
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I was careless just because my project completion time was reduced.

Comment: "I'm having a hard time". Please be more specific. What is the expected result and actual result? `strcmp(line, "//")` is not what you need in this case. It does an exact match which isn't what you are after if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fscanf` is wrong. It won't return `EOF`. You want to compare against `!= 1` instead.

But, if you want to strip the comment, and just print the [preceding] data, you'll want `strstr` instead of `strcmp`

Also, I'd use `fgets` instead of `fscanf` ...

Here's your code refactored:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH     1000

void
read_file(char *filename)
{
    int flag = 0;
    char *cp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (1) {
        cp = fgets(line,sizeof(line),f);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        cp = strstr(line,"//");

        if (cp != NULL) {
            *cp++ = '\n';
            *cp = 0;
        }

        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

You may want to clean this up a bit more to do better handling of the newline [which `fgets` retains].

---

**UPDATE:**

> Yes, my code is fixed. Thank you so much. But I don't understand here : *c = 0

A string in C is a `char` array that just "happens" to have a zero byte as the string terminator.

`fgets` will guarantee that the buffer has a trailing 0

Likewise, `printf` expects `line` to be 0 terminated.

We're trying to clip out the `//` and everything else on the line that follows it.

It's not enough to just add back a newline there. We have to add [back] the 0 at the now shortened string as the new place for the string terminator.

If the original line was:

```
foo // bar<newline><0x00>
```

We want:

```
foo <newline><0x00>
```

If you want to see why, just comment out the `*cp = 0;`. You'll get "interesting" results ...

---

**UPDATE #2:**

In order to *not* change your code so much, I left the newline in the string.

But, normally, I always strip the newline out before doing any processing. I find that to be a bit cleaner [even if a bit slower].

Here's a version that does that and is closer to what I would have written from scratch:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH     1000

void
read_file(char *filename)
{
    int flag = 0;
    char *cp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (1) {
        cp = fgets(line,sizeof(line),f);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline
        cp = strchr(line,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        // find [and strip] the comment
        cp = strstr(line,"//");
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
}
```

Note that because the newline has been pre-stripped [*if* it exists on the line], the `printf` has to be modified to add one when printing.

---

**UPDATE #3:**

Using `strchr` and `strstr` are the *easy* thing to do. But, this requires that `line` be scanned *twice*, which is a bit wasteful.

The `str*` functions in `libc` are a *convenience*, but we can write a custom function that does a single pass on the line and strips either the comment or the newline whichever comes first.

This may help explain what a "string" in C really is, since we're doing "all the magic" so to speak:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH     1000

void
fixline(char *line)
{
    int chr;

    for (chr = *line++;  chr != 0;  chr = *line++) {
        // strip newline
        if (chr == '\n') {
            line[-1] = 0;
            break;
        }

        // wait for first "/"
        if (chr != '/')
            continue;

        // peek at next char (is it '/' -- if so, we have "//")
        chr = *line;
        if (chr == '/') {
            line[-1] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void
read_file(char *filename)
{
    int flag = 0;
    char *cp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (1) {
        cp = fgets(line,sizeof(line),f);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline and/or comment
        fixline(line);

        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #4:**

> Thank you I got it. But when I try it this way, why can't I get the right result? `if(!strcmp("data", line)) { printf("helloo"); } break;` When you add this part to the end of the code, it doesn't work correctly.

If you've added this after the newline strip, it should work, because the `data` line has nothing else on it *and* it starts in the first position of the buffer.

But, indented this is:

```
if (!strcmp("data", line)) {
    printf("helloo");
}
break;
```

You probably want:

```
if (!strcmp("data", line)) {
    printf("helloo");
    break;
}
```

Both `strchr` and `strstr` *scan* the entire string looking for a matching character [`strchr`]. Or, the *start* of matching substring [`strstr`].

`strcmp` does *not* scan the string in *that* sense. It just loops through both strings, char-by-char and stops on EOS. It just checks for equal strings, both starting at the first char of each array.

Real `strcmp` will use special instructions to make it *very* fast [as will other `libc` functions], but here is what `strcmp` actually does:

```
int
strcmp(const char *s1,const char *s2)
{
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int cmp = 0;

    while (1) {
        c1 = *s1++;
        c2 = *s2++;

        if (c1 < c2) {
            cmp = -1;
            break;
        }

        if (c1 > c2) {
            cmp = +1;
            break;
        }

        // end of string -- both strings equal
        if (c1 == 0)
            break;
    }

    return cmp;
}
```

Comment: Yes, my code is fixed. Thank you so much. But I don't understand here : *c = 0

Comment: Thank you I got it. But when I try it this way, why can't I get the right result?                                  
       if(!strcmp("data", line)) {
            printf("helloo");
        }
        break;                                                                             When you add this part to the end of the code, it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I really thank you very much. You have been very helpful.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Don't forget to upvote good answers and accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Format `%s` reads words (i.e. everything until the next space, tab, newline, ...) but not lines; That's probably why you have a hard time.

For reading in complete lines (i.e. everything up to a new line), use function `fgets`;

For cutting the line off at a `"//"`, use `strstr` as follows:

```
char *beginOfComment = strstr(line,"//");
if (beginOfComment) {
   *beginOfComment = 0x0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Craig Estey

```
    while (1)
    {

        cp = fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        if(!strcmp("actions", cp)) {
            break;
        }
        cp = strstr(line, "//");

        if (cp != NULL)
        {
            *cp++ = '\n';
            *cp = 0;
        }

        printf("%s", line);
    }
```

Why is the strcmp function not working in this way?